# How do I Use FastMember to create a reader of an object with child object

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy, idatareader, fastmember

We need to `SQLBulkCopy` a collection that we have. And since we need an IDataReader to use SQLBulkCopy, I tried to use FastMember for that. As I understand, we can use `FastMember` to create an `IDataReader` from an IEnumerable.

So my code reads-

```
using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(customer.Records)
{
    DataAccess.BulkInsert(serverName, databaseName, tableName, reader);
}
```

But the issue is that each record has a child object called which has further properties in it that i want to have in data reader so that they can be inserted into the table in database. But cant find a way to get a flatten `IDataReader`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by creating an `anonymous object` and filling it up with the values that we needed. This way you can flatten out your object and use only the properties that you need.

```
var newObjects = customer.Records.Select(record => new
{
    customer.Id,
    record.DisplayName,
    record.TotalCount,
    record.Conditions.IsActive,
    record.Conditions.SusperCondition.IsSuper,
    Status = (int)record.Status
});
```

Then just pass this new object to `ObjectReader`

```
using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(newObjects))
{
    DataAccess.BulkInsert(serverName, databaseName, tableName, reader, SetBulkCopyMappings);
}
```

Bulk Insert -

```
internal static void BulkInsert(string serverName, string databaseName, string tableName, IDataReader dataReader, Action<SqlBulkCopy> setMappings)
    {
        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(BuildConnectionString(serverName, databaseName)))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
            setMappings(bulkCopy);
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataReader);
        }
    }
```